# Cоздание документа формата doc

Tags: java

Каким образом создать документ формата doc ? Если можно, с примером

Answer (score 2):

С помощью [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;

public class CreateDocument {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
      HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(); 

      try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("example.doc"))) {
          document.write(out);
      }
   }
}
```